# Multiple providers for aws_kms_replica_key resouce.How to pass them to module and it will work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-kms

all!
i have issue creating kms key replica in different region.
We have main provider.tf where i am declaring both aws providers in different regions

```
`terraform {

  backend "s3" {}

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      #
      #version = "3.52"
      version = "4.33"
    }

     }

  required_version = ">= 1.0.0"

}

provider “aws” {
alias = “primary”
region = var.env_vars[var.environment].region

default_tags {
tags = {
Owner = lower(var.owner)
Environment = lower(var.environment)
Build_tag = var.build_tag
#Backup = var.env_vars[var.environment].backup
}
}
}

provider “aws” {
alias = “replica”
region = var.env_vars[“replica”].region
}
```

then inside main.tf i am calling kms module like

```
module “kms” {
source = “./modules/kms”

account_id = local.account_id
aws_accounts = module.organization.accounts
providers = {
aws.primary = aws.primary
aws.replica = aws.replica
}
}`
```

in ./modules/kms/provider.tf

```
`terraform {
required_providers {
aws = {
source = “hashicorp/aws”
version = “4.33”
configuration_aliases = [ aws.primary, aws.replica ]
}
}
}
`
```

and in ./modules/kms/main.tf

```
`resource “aws_kms_key” “backupvault” {
provider = aws.primary
description = “KMS key used for account level backups”
is_enabled = true
multi_region = true
policy = jsonencode(…)
}

resource “aws_kms_alias” “backupvault” {
provider = aws.primary
name = “alias/aws-z-z-z-z-kms-z-backup-z”
target_key_id = aws_kms_key.backupvault.id
}

resource “aws_kms_replica_key” “backupvault” {
description = “Multi-region replica backupvault key”
primary_key_arn = aws_kms_key.backupvault.arn

provider = aws.replica
}`
```

and i am getting errors
Error: Missing required provider configuration
│
│ on main.tf line 134:
│ 134: module “kms” {
│
│ The child module requires an additional configuration for provider hashicorp/aws, with the local name “aws.primary”.
│
│ Refer to the module’s documentation to understand the intended purpose of this additional provider configuration, and then add an entry for aws.primary in the “providers” meta-argument in the module block
│ to choose which provider configuration the module should use for that purpose.
╵
╷
│ Error: Missing required provider configuration
│
│ on main.tf line 134:
│ 134: module “kms” {
│
│ The child module requires an additional configuration for provider hashicorp/aws, with the local name “aws.replica”.
│
│ Refer to the module’s documentation to understand the intended purpose of this additional provider configuration, and then add an entry for aws.replica in the “providers” meta-argument in the module block
│ to choose which provider configuration the module should use for that purpose.
╵

I am wondering if it can be because backend-config we are defining region but i guess no…

to create replica of the key in other region

Comment: module “kms” {
source = “./modules/kms”

account_id = local.account_id
aws_accounts = module.organization.accounts
providers = {
aws= aws.primary # or aws=aws.replica 

}`